# Unable to share Google Script: internal error has occured

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to share a simple Google Script created under my account.

However, upon sharing I am getting an internal server error (see [this video](https://www.cloudhq.net/screencast/044e55a1784892.webm)).

There is no further information how to proceed.

What can I try to successfully share my script?

[image]

Comment: If you can create your videos as gifs you can import them to SO with the image import tool. I use to have problems sharing scripts without recopying them.  However, with a business account you can give the other person full access and copy stuff to the shared drive and they can copy it and it's now theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to share a script attached to a Spreadsheet, which is not possible. You should share the Spreadsheet instead, or copy the code and create a new [Project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/projects) with only the Script.